Laravel mutators (<model>::all working, DB::table(<table>)->get() not)
I have mutators of this type in my model1 that replace the decimal separator with a semicolon:
protected function fee(): Attribute{
    return Attribute::make(
        get: fn (?string $value) => str_replace('.', ',', $value) ?: 0,
        set: fn (?string $value) => str_replace(',', '.', $value) ?: 0,
    );
}

when I pass them to blade with:
Model1::all()

the mutators work and print me for example:
1,50

when I pass them to blade with (I have filters to perform):
$model1 = DB::table('model1');
$model1->where(....);
$model1->get();

the mutators do not worked and print:
1.50

What am I doing wrong?

Mutators work only when you use laravel eloquent models not with DB facades

but is it possible to perform filters with the eloquent model?

When you call DB::table(...), you get Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder, not a model instance so mutator will not work.

so the models are not filterable? I'm a bit confused sorry...

Model::where(...)->get() is a perfectly valid query... What do you mean "Models are not filterable"? If you have multiple filters, then $query = Model::query();, then $query->where(...); $query->get();. Read the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/eloquent#retrieving-models. Laravel would be a pretty bad framework if Model queries weren't a thing and you could only use Model::all() lol...

ci sono riuscito!
così funziona:
[code block]
$filter = [];
if ($request->input('val1')){
$filter = ['col1'] => $request->input('val1')];
}
if ($request->input('val2')){
$filter += ['col2'] => $request->input('val2')];
}
    $model1 = Model1::where($filter)->get();

[/code block]
così invece no:
[code block]
$model1 = Model1::all();
if ($request->input('val1')){
$model->where('col1', $request->input('val1'));
}
...
$model->get();
[/code block]

Glad that worked, but please A) do not post content in other languages; English is required on Stackoverflow, and B) do not post code blocks in the comments. You can edit your question or post an answer below.

Mutators only work with eloquent model,when you work with DB::table,You are not using model layer to communicate with database,you are connecting to database directly,so all mutators,accessors,cast properties and ... you have defined in model layer doesnt participate in your request lifecycle.
